# Create jQuery plugin with initial call and also override defaults

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Basically i want to create a jquery plugin that will display loading animation on page load. Creating a jquery for it was easy part.

You can see here:

```
$.fn.prelodr = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        delay: 1000,
    }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        var $elm = $(this)
          , d = settings.delay;
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.preloadback').delay(d).slideUp(300);
        });
    });
}
```

and using `$('.preloadback').prelodr();` I use this function.
Now, I have this loader on more than one pages, so I moved this code to js file and included it in project. It works without a problem.

Problem: 
I want to supply delay option using

```
$('.preloadback').prelodr({delay:5000,});
```

I use this function-call from document footer. Issue is it is getting called twice. How do I keep initial function call in js file and also override default option from page?

Answer (score 0):

If your call with the custom delay happens first, you could set a flag on that element to ignore it on the second call.

```
$.fn.prelodr = function(options) {
    var settings = $.extend({
        delay: 1000,
    }, options);
    return this.each(function() {
        var $elm = $(this)
          , d = settings.delay;

        if($elm.data('prelodr-loaded')) { return; }
        else { $elm.data('prelodr-loaded', true); }

        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.preloadback').delay(d).slideUp(300);
        });
    });
}
```